# How to Solve This Issue in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You could use Android Studio because ADT will never be updated anymore

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think, It's time to move on to `Android Studio` ?

**Note : they have stopped providing support for android development on eclipse.**

Answer (score 0):

where appear that mensage? is in the Graphical Layout of the xml files?

if so, just change the version of the api

is the Android simbol in the top of the Graphical Layout Screen, in mine appear the Android Simbol with the number 25 - that mean Api 25: Android 7.1 I change that to Api 19 and work fine